What is the minimal copy&paste way to apply a converting constructor using std::ranges::views::transform?
I am working on a constexpr parser, which parses a text file and generates an object representation.
I am using G++ 14.1.0, but would also be fine to switch (right now I have the feeling G++ supports more of recent C++ than CLang).
I am using std::ranges::views::split there a lot and then convert the values to std::string_view via std::ranges::views::split.
Minimal example code:
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    constexpr auto working =
        input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv) |
        std::ranges::views::transform(
            [](const auto input) { return std::string_view(input); });
}

Because this is a lot of copy&paste and makes the code hard to read I tried to move the call of the converting constructor or even the whole transformation into a constexpr function.
The first I tried was:
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    constexpr auto working =
        input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv) |
        std::ranges::views::transform(std::string_view::string_view);
}

,which results in the error: 'string_view' is not a member of 'std::string_view' {aka 'std::basic_string_view<char>'}
and:
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    constexpr auto working =
        input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv) |
        std::ranges::views::transform(std::string_view);
}

,which results in the error: expected primary-expression before ')'.
The third I tried was:
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

[[nodiscard]] static constexpr std::string_view to_string_view(const auto input)
    requires(std::constructible_from<std::string_view, decltype(input)>)
{
    return std::string_view(input);
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    constexpr auto test = std::ranges::views::transform(
        input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv), to_string_view);
}

, which results in error
> <source>: In function 'int main()':
> <source>:15:56: error: no match for call to '(const std::ranges::views::_Transform) (std::ranges::split_view<std::basic_string_view<char>, std::basic_string_view<char> >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
>    15 |     constexpr auto test = std::ranges::views::transform(
>       |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>.   16 |         input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv), to_string_view);
>       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> In file included from <source>:2:
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges:2212:9: note: candidate: 'template<class _Range, class _Fp>  requires (viewable_range<_Range>) && (__can_transform_view<_Range, _Fp>) constexpr auto std::ranges::views::_Transform::operator()(_Range&&, _Fp&&) const'
>  2212 |         operator() [[nodiscard]] (_Range&& __r, _Fp&& __f) const
>       |         ^~~~~~~~
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges:2212:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> <source>:15:56: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Fp'
>.   15 |     constexpr auto test = std::ranges::views::transform(
>       |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>    16 |         input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv), to_string_view);
>       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges:991:9: note: candidate: 'template<class ... _Args>  requires  __adaptor_partial_app_viable<_Derived, _Args ...> constexpr auto std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<_Derived>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Derived = std::ranges::views::_Transform]'
>   991 |         operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
>       |         ^~~~~~~~
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges:991:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges:991:9: note: constraints not satisfied
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges: In substitution of 'template<class ... _Args>  requires  __adaptor_partial_app_viable<_Derived, _Args ...> constexpr auto std::ranges::views::__adaptor::_RangeAdaptor<std::ranges::views::_Transform>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = std::ranges::views::_Transform]':
> <source>:15:56:   required from here
>    15 |     constexpr auto test = std::ranges::views::transform(
>       |                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
>    16 |         input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv), to_string_view);
>       |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges:921:13:   required for the satisfaction of '__adaptor_partial_app_viable<_Derived, _Args ...>' [with _Derived = std::ranges::views::_Transform; _Args = {}]
> /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20240629/include/c++/15.0.0/ranges:922:28: note: the expression 'sizeof ... (_Args ...) == (_Adaptor::_S_arity) - 1 [with _Args = {}; _Adaptor = std::ranges::views::_Transform]' evaluated to 'false'
>   922 |       && (sizeof...(_Args) == _Adaptor::_S_arity - 1)
>       |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Compiler returned: 1

I guess the problem here is, that to_string_view is not instantiated for specific types and thus the compiler does not find it, but this is a guess.
So I tried to try directly the anyway final goal and move the whole transformation into a function:
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

static auto constexpr to_string_transform_view = std::bind_back(
    std::ranges::views::transform, [](const auto input)
        requires(std::constructible_from<std::string_view, decltype(input)>)
    { return std::string_view(input); });

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    auto constexpr test =
        to_string_transform_view(input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv));
}

Help needed: This compiles, but I loose the nice | syntax, which is much better to read. How could I improve this in a way that the definition of to_string_transform_view does not get (too much) worse to read?
Also I, OK now only one time, have this "ugly" lambda function there for a really simple thing.
Because I need this also for other things, I would prefer there a better way.
Thanks to various answers in StackOverflow, I saw that boost gives there two options:

boost::value_factory:

#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

#include <boost/functional/value_factory.hpp>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

static auto constexpr to_string_transform_view = std::bind_back(
    std::ranges::views::transform, boost::value_factory<std::string_view>());

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    auto constexpr test =
        to_string_transform_view(input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv));
}


boost::lambda::constructor

#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

#include <boost/lambda/construct.hpp>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

static auto constexpr to_string_transform_view = std::bind_back(
    std::ranges::views::transform, boost::lambda::constructor<std::string_view>());

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    auto constexpr test =
        to_string_transform_view(input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv));
}

Questions to thaT:

Are there just two implementations for the same thing?
Is one for some cases better suited than the other?
Is there a way without requiring third-party libraries?


Unfortunately, ranges::to requires that C must not satisfy view, so we currently can't use it like
input | std::views::split(","sv)
      | std::views::transform(ranges::to<std::string_view>());

However, it is possible to make a function object that converts between types to pass into views::transform, for example
template<class To>
inline constexpr auto static_caster = 
  []<class From>(From&& from) -> To
    requires requires { static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>()); }
  { return static_cast<To>(std::forward<From>(from)); };

constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
/* constexpr */ auto working =
  input | std::views::split(","sv)
        | std::views::transform(static_caster<std::string_view>);

Note that split_view is not const-iterable, i.e. its begin() is not const-qualified, so its const object is not a range.

You don't need to apply std::bind_back to a range adaptor object. Calling std::ranges::views::transform with a single argument is equivalent to using std::bind_back, and additionally supports the | syntax.
Simply remove bind_back and it will just work.
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;

constexpr auto to_string_transform_view =
    std::ranges::views::transform([](const auto input)
        requires(std::constructible_from<std::string_view, decltype(input)>)
    { return std::string_view(input); });

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view input = "A,B B,C C,D C,E D,F"sv;
    constexpr auto test =
        input | std::ranges::views::split(","sv) | to_string_transform_view;
}

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xc95b6hYf
